# Observable as input for Directive

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-directive

i have a directive which i want to add @Input observable to handle success and failure scenarios of http observable through this directive

```
Directive({
        selector: '[search]'
    })

    export class SearchDirective implements OnInit, OnChanges, OnDestroy {
    @Input() searchObs = new Subject();

ngOnInit() {
this.sub = this.searchObs.subscribe(
    data => console.log(data),
    err => console.log(err._body),
    () => console.log('directive completed')
);
}

ngOnDestroy() {
this.sub.unsubscribe();
}

ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    // tslint:disable-next-line:forin
    for (let propName in changes) {
        let change = changes[propName];
        if (propName === 'searchObs') {
            this.searchObs = (change.currentValue as Subject<any>);
                this.sub = this.searchObs.subscribe(
                    data => console.log(data),
                    err => console.log(err._body),
                    () => console.log('directive change  completed')
                );
        }
      }
  }
}
```

and my component api observable is

```
  searchObs = new Subject();
this.apiservice.getData(args).subscribe((data) => {
      this.searchObs.next(data);
    }, err => {
      this.searchObs.error(err);
    });
  }
```

what happens now that i got the first value of subscription whether it was the success or Error in the directive and then no data is binding to the directive.

Comment: in your directive, `@Input() searchObs = new Subject();` this part will replace the input from component, just define the `@input` as a subject

Comment: @JimmyHo i tried it and i got this error `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined` and when i made it as `new Subject` i got the previous behavior only run for once
i notice  that if it was success i can get the new data in the directive. it fails only on error handling scenario. this when using `new Subject()`

Comment: @JimmyHo i figure out that the `subject` when it got error it closed and cannot be resumed or call `subject.next()` or `subject.error()` any more so in my api observable service i redefine the `subject` and t all values is binding now to my directive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue was that `Subject` error handling close the `Subject` on `Subject.error()` so i redfine it again after error

Component.ts

```
this.apiservice.getData(args).subscribe((data) => {
      this.searchObs.next(data);
    }, err => {
      this.searchObs.error(err);
       this.searchObs = new Subject();
    });
  }
```